# CSS method to select all elements with any id

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select all h2 with any id.

I've tried `h2#*` which is invalid, and I've tried attribute selectors `h2[id*='']`, but this won't accept a wildcard, and leaving it empty (as above, nothing between the quotes) doesn't match anything.

Is there anything I've missed, or is this just a dead-end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector. It's not necessary to supply a value. This should select all `h2` elements with an `id` attribute, whether or not it has a value:

```
h2[id] {/* ... */}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `h2`, and nothing more. This selects all the h2 items in your code. If you only want the items with a specified ID, use `h2[id]`.